# How to loop over soft deleted items on contract?

Tags: solidity

I have a smart contract that contains posts. Let's say that it's a twitter-like dapp.

```
Contract Blog {
    struct Post {
        string content;
        bool isDeleted;
    }
    mapping (uint256 => Post) private posts;
    uint256 postCounter = 0;
}
```

In this contract, I have a get method that returns post if post is not deleted.

```
function get(uint256 index) public view returns (string memory) {
    Post memory post = posts[index];
    required(post.isDeleted == false, "This post is deleted.")
    return post.text
}
```

In this case, when I need to loop over Tweets I'm something like this on the frontend.

```
Get num of posts from the contract = X
for (let i=0; i<=X; i++) {
   try {
       post = try to get post from contract.
   } except {
       if contract returns error suppress it
       continue
   }
}
```

Most of the time the frontend side is trying to consume the contract for non-existing posts. Is there any better approach to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Comment: Using an iteratable mapping may work for you. Also I'd suggest to only use requires in views when the condition will cause a revert.

Comment: @Ismael there's no case at there like described here.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by returning deleted posts with a flag.

```
function get(uint256 index) public view returns (bool, string memory) {
    Post memory post = posts[index];
    return (post.deleted, post.text)
}
```

Then after on frontend side I'm using that deleted flag to not to show.

```
Get num of posts from the contract = X
for (let i=0; i<=X; i++) {
    isDeleted, text = try to get post from contract.
    if (isDeleted) {
        continue (or show an empty post that describes that is deleted)
    } else {
        render post
    }
}
```